# Clean XML string of number and point using str_replace array

Tags: php, xml

I have some XML that I need to clean to be plain English categories. The plugin I am using uses `:` to distinguish values so I just need to process the XML string to remove any other characters, particularly numbers and a point, for example `1.` or `12.`

**Sample XML**

```
<keywords> 1. News:Other News </keywords>
```

**PHP function**

```
function processCategories($categories) {
    return str_replace(array("/[0-9]+/", "."), "", $categories);    
}
```

**Current output**

`1 News : Other News`

So other news is written in perfectly and is recognised as an existing category but the `str_replace` hasn't removed the numbers? Also, is it worth using `trim` to remove the whitespace around the values?

Comment: Do you want to remove only start digit?

Comment: @splash58 I'd like to remove any numbers present. Essentially, I need my string to be `News:Other News:Food:Sport` so any numbers and points that occur, anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use preg_replace

```
return str_replace(str_split('0123456789.'), '' ,$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK str_replace only handles string literals, not regular expressions. You need to use preg_replace instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php